# SQL Server Express 2008 installation problem

Tags: sql-server-2008

I just installed SQL Server Express 2008 on my Windows 2003 server.

The sql base is started, but I look in config manager and my SQL Server browser is not started. I can't start it. When I try to change properties, I got an error: there's no enable device associate (0x800704).

I will look for reinstalling SQL Server browser manually ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087.aspx ). I don't know if that will cause an error. Maybe the same thing I got before.

I try to reinstall/repair, but there's an error (my biggest problem is that I'm not the admin of this server, so I need to wait for the tech to be there if I want to do something. Last timed, I didn't have the time to get all information. I need to get all ideas and program before, because I will have not so much time to try to repair it. The server is used by other users (data), and I can't reboot often)

If you have any idea, what should I do, or Test, or hit?

thank you

Comment: Do you really want to enable the Browser service? All it does is publish that the SQL Server is on the network. It's disabled by default for security reasons.

Comment: I need to connect to the db from local network. And for the moment I cant, I was thinking that its the browser who do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install SQL Sever properly -- and have all the services running as expected -- you really should be logged in as an administrator.

Comment: I was log as admin (in install mod). I did not have any error before I try to change sql server browser. (otherwise sql connection error, thats probably because the sql server browser is off)

Comment: After retry to restart the sql server browser I finally found a way, just som little thing to change. I didnt have much time when I install (and I never really touch the computer, I dont have the right)